# What's going on with my flag?

Tags: discussion, flagging, exact-duplicates, moderation, specific-flag

While waiting for Alex Gruber to recharge his batteries, the moderation is working slowly. For instance, on September 3 I've voted to close [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907478/let-r-be-an-integral-domain-which-is-not-a-field-then-can-rx-have-a-maxim) as a duplicate. I was certain from the very beginning that my vote is a waste of time, since one needs some knowledge and willingness to perceive why that question is a duplicate, and after some hours I've decided to flag the question as a duplicate, counting on the moderators attention. I was right, and the question was closed as a duplicate, but surprisingly, reopened instantly by Pedro Tamaroff. I supposed this happened because the moderator closed the question as a duplicate of [How to find solutions of linear Diophantine ax + by = c?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20717/how-to-find-solutions-of-linear-diophantine-ax-by-c), an obvious mistake. So far, so good. I've flagged the question again as a duplicate, mentioning the possible mistake made by the moderator. Since then my flag is pending. So let me ask:

> Dear moderators, what's going on with my flag?

Comment: Why are you wasting the moderators' time by flagging things as duplicate rather than casting votes like you are supposed to?

Comment: Is it alright with you if a non-moderator answers this post?  If not, then you might want to communicate with the moderators privately instead of publicly like this.

Comment: I think the questions just are not duplicates. If I were a mod, I would think the flag should be declined  but since another mod already was on the question I might well leave it to this particular one.   I do understand that the post you mentioned in the comment and one of the dupe targets in the closure give specific examples and thus in  a way answer the question, but this does not make the questions duplicates. Abstractly the question "Is there an example of Phenomenon P?" is not duplicate of "Verify this particular thing that happens to be instance of Phenomenon P."

Comment: Should this be tagged ([meta-tag:specific-flag])? Or is this about discussing a more general issue and the links and the mentioned flags serve only as an illustration?

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that in [the close votes review](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/675593) there were two close votes and three votes to leave open.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft If I understand [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21547/what-is-the-difference-between-voting-to-close-as-a-duplicate-and-flagging-as-a/21548#21548) correctly, flagging as a duplicate and casting duplicate close vote do *exactly the same thing* for 3k+ users.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I do not quite understand your comment. OP explains (my emphasis) "on September 3 **I've voted to close** this question as a duplicate. I was certain from the very beginning that my vote is a waste of time, since one needs some knowledge and willingness to perceive why that question is a duplicate, and after some hours I've decided to flag the question as a duplicate," Looking at the review-history it appears the gap was rather even larger, and in any case the question was likely past review when the post was flagged (for mod attention).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I took OP to mean they cast a mod attention flag "other"; I' be surprised one can flag as duplicate (in the technical sense) after one voted as duplicate (and the vote did not expire, but us pending or took effect). Also note the "mentioning the possible mistake made by the moderator" which makes sense in the context of an "other" flag yet not a duplicate flag.

Comment: @quid Letting aside the specific case, talking in general: In the case of *non-obvious duplicates* I think that it would be advisable if the close voter explain in comments *why* the post is a duplicate. (Some reviewers do look at the comments.) Other possible action would be mention it in [the dedicated chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2165/c-r-u-d-e). And I'd guess that non-obvious duplicates would be ideal for the dedicated thread - creation of such thread was suggested [not so long ago](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/23643). I think that the actions mentioned...

Comment: ...here would be preferable to flagging for moderators attention. (Or at least they are worth trying before flagging for mods attention.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak yes, I agree with all of this.

Comment: @quid If the question is not a duplicate, then how can you explain that the answer is the same?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I've communicated with the mods by flags. If you know other ways to communicate with them about a particular question please let me know.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Please read at least the first two sentences of my question before posting a comment. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinSleziak No need to explain anything in this case. The answer from the comments and the accepted answer of the question are the same as the answers to other two questions. Btw, I'm not surprise that three votes were "leave open". Voting to close such a question suppose to *think*.

Comment: @user26857 To me the statements that *"one needs some knowledge and willingness to perceive why that question is a duplicate"* and that there is *"No need to explain anything in this case"* seem to contradict each other. But as I mentioned, my comment was more about non-obvious duplicates in general rather than about this specific situation.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Maybe, but as I already told you I'm not very interested in wasting much time on meta, and even less in such subtleties. I just wanted to point out a case where the moderation doesn't work very well, while a moderator can take more than a month break and people say it's ok. (Btw, I'm eager to see the tag `minimal-ideals`.)

Comment: The point is that the current question also allows *other* answers that would not answer the dupe target. When the question is closed as dupe there is no place to give them.

Comment: I am not sure what the remark about minimal-ideals has to do with this question. I would suggest to take the discussion about tags [where it belongs](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2016/9/7), so that we do not discuss here issues that are entirely unrelated to the original question.

Comment: @MartinSleziak If you edited one of the questions related to the one I'm talking about here, by adding the unneccessary tag `maximal-ideals`, then I can say that I'm waiting to see the tag `minimal-ideals` :) I feel this tag is missing :)

Comment: Btw, dear commenters (who commented about everything, but not on what I'm interested in): don't you think that four days to handle a flag is a little long?

Comment: Do you want to contradict the claim? It  would be weird given that you link to questions with different answers each of which would answer the current questions while they are not interchangeable on the targets. We recently had a similar discussion related to non-UFDs IIRC. I consider it as a problem that questions seeking example and understanding of a phenomenon are closed as dupes of specialized questions discussing one example. It would seem better to aggregate the different examples in the more general post. Rather then to send all readers on a chase through *several* "duplicates."

Comment: @quid I have invited you to post an answer which differ to the linked ones and reflecting a phenomenon that I've missed. Once again: go ahead!

Comment: "If I were a mod, I would think the flag should be declined but since another mod already was on the question I might well leave it to this particular one." <- attempted to explain why this flag could take a while. Other than that I have a flag pending since more than a month on another site. I'd relax a bit.

Comment: @quid I'm relaxed, I think :)

Comment: It seems your point is that there is a unifying point of view that allows to recognize the different particular examples as only superficially different and ultimately the same. Indeed this would be an example of an answer that could nicely fit the general question. (If anything, though I do not propose it, the specific instances then could be closed as dupes of the more general one.) " I'm relaxed, I think :)" Glad to hear that. :-)

Comment: "It seems your point is that there is a unifying point of view that allows to recognize the different particular examples as only superficially different and ultimately the same." You got my point! Well, this is also clearly said under [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1907522/121097).

Comment: Slightly ironically the relatively clearest mention is indeed under the supposed dupe-question,  not on the targets. Anyway, I still think the reasonable course of action would be to give this as answer in straight forward terms, possibly linking the existing posts for details of the argument, rather than via oblique reference. By the way, you seemed to imply this is the only case when this can happen, but it is not said anywhere explicitly, so I am not sure if you claim this. (I also do not know if its true, but it seems plausible, in any case for domains.)

Comment: @user26857, you could also communicate with the moderators using the [Math Mods' Office](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office) chatroom.  (It is still "public," but it is not as "public" as meta.)

Comment: I do not want to be impertinent but irrespective of all dupe debate  I'd now be actually curious if "this is the only case when this can happen". Do you happen to know this?

Answer (score 13):

> "I was certain from the very beginning that my vote is a waste of time, since one needs some knowledge and willingness to perceive why that question is a duplicate, ..."

I'm willing to grant that Readers are lucky to have knowledgeable and willing experts such as yourself on this topic to spot the connection that is hidden to most of us.  But would it not be more expeditious to post an Answer explaining the connection, rather than engage in a Close-as-Duplicate contest?

Closing as duplicate is [intended to manage exact or nearly-exact duplicates](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates), not cases where the answer to one Question is an essential tool to resolve another Question.  Closing as duplicates aids in the Search process, and so helps Readers find information they seek.  When some deduction is not obvious, it bears pointing out for the sake of future Readers.